# can not able to login to admin panel

Tags: admin-panel, fatal-error

I am trying to login from the admin side of my site. But it is not logging me in with the correct user-name and password provided.

I cleared browser history and tried in other browsers also.

It gives me an error :

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:
>   Mage::$_isDeveloperMode in /home//public_html/one/em0113-full-package
>   /app/Mage.php on line 881

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: its really the greatest co incidence that, after posting 1st answer in  `Aug 24 '15 `  exactly after 1 year, 2nd answer is posted on `Aug 24 '16 `.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect a core hack here. The error is pointing to this lines of code :

```
public static function getIsDeveloperMode()
{
    return self::$_isDeveloperMode;
}
```

The method simply returns a static property `$_isDeveloperMode` of the class `app\Mage.php`. You can find that the definition of that static property in that file itself in line 117 (magento 1.9.1) like this.

```
static private $_isDeveloperMode = false;
```

So what you need to do here is, either add this single line inside `app\Mage.php` or

the best option is replace your BADLY HACKED `Mage.php` file with the default `Mage.php` file. You didn't specify the version of Magento used. So use `Mage.php` file from same version.

Comment: i replaced the Mage.php its worked....

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 that's it. Happy to hear that it helped

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't update Mage.php file.

This issue can be easily resolved by either of the following methods:

1. In index.php look for the following code:
   if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
   Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
   }

Change "true" to "false"

2.In .htaccess you should see something like :
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true

Comment this code out so it will be #SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true

Comment: Welcome to community , you are absolutely right, Thanks a lot for your guidance, i remember i replaced original Mage.php file , cheers :-)