# How to remove authentication massages in magento website which is hacked by someone

Tags: secure, core-hacks

I have a **Magento website**. Someone add adds on my **homepage in  header section**. 
When I click on my websites menus then other links are opening there.

How can I remove it and how to secure in future for this happening?
You can see my website on top some adds running I wanna remove it.

Plz help me. My admin panel is not opening.

I have login and password details. When i login with user name and password the it's not open after that in footer a massages is displaying that .

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Mage::$_isDeveloperMode in /home/rahul1988/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 880
```

my Website is

http://borsavela.com/

Comment: check once @Baby in Magento question here. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/can-not-able-to-login-to-admin-panel

Answer (score 0):

You can login to admin panel in http://borsavela.com/admin url.
If you don't have access, you have permissions to database, right?

You should remove all admin users and create new with better password by DB;)

Comment: I have login and password details when i fill user name and password the it's not open after that in footer a massages is displaying that .... Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Mage::$_isDeveloperMode in /home/rahul1988/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 880

Comment: Ahhh I see, please read http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/can-not-able-to-login-to-admin-panel It should help ;)