# Can't login it shows fatel error

Tags: magento-1, fatal-error

When we try to **login** to **admin** it shows **fatal error**. So is there any solution for this problem?

Fatal error:

> Access to undeclared static property: Mage::$_isDeveloperMode in /home/mominaslib/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 881

Comment: What version of Magento are you running? What is the fatal error? Can you copy/paste it here.

Comment: It shows this ""Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Mage::$_isDeveloperMode in /home/mominaslib/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 881"""

Comment: You modify your mage.php file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd give https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79637/41117 a read.

If you've made any changes to `Mage.php` then I suggest replacing it to the default version from your Magento 1 install and trying again.